# Connectivity between SQL server and VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, connection

I am not able to establish connection between SQL server and a VBA form. It's throwing the following error

Compiler Error:
User-defined type not defined

Here's the code with server details:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
  Dim cnn As ADODB.Command
  Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
  Set cnn = New ADODB.Command
  cnn.Open "Provider=sqloledb;" & _
           "Data Source=<IP>;" & _
           "Initial Catalog=<DB>;" & _
           "User Id=<USER>;" & _
           "Password=<PASS>"
  MsgBox "connection successful"
  cnn.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't include ip/user/password information in a public post. Edited to remove.

Comment: Did you notice that you're dimensioning `cnn` twice? Or is it just a typo here at SO?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a reference to `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects X.X Library` where X.X is the ADO version.

You will then get an error on your second line because you are trying to re-declare your `cnn` variable.